# Javascript radio display none/inline

Tags: javascript

In my HTML code I have this two inputs:

```
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="RadioCheck()" name="radio" id="yes" /> 
No <input type="radio" onclick="RadioCheck()" name="radio" id="no"  />
```

Now I have a div that is by default as it's style display inline, and I want that when I click no it makes it style display none and yes will make it inline, so I made this function

```
function RadioCheck() {
    var Radioclick = document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display;
    if (Radioclick == "inline") {
        document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (Radioclick == "none") {
        document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I don't know how to do it that when I click yes it will switch to inline and if I click yes again it will stay inline instead of switching it to none, I know my code just switch between inline to none but I want it to make it inline when yes radio is clicked and none when no radio is clicked without two functions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could pass a variable to the RadioCheck() function?

```
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="RadioCheck(true)" name="radio" id="yes" /> 
No <input type="radio" onclick="RadioCheck(false)" name="radio" id="no"  />
```

And then in your javascript:

```
function RadioCheck(isYes){
    if(isYes){
        document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `div`'s display to be determined by the radio button checked, the condition should be on the radio checked:

```
if the Yes radio button is checked
    show the div
if the No radio button is checked
    hide the div
```

So:

```
if (document.getElementById("yes").checked) {
    document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display = "inline";
}
if (document.getElementById("no").checked) {
    document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display = "none";
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/39cMn/ for an working example

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `value` attribute to your radio buttons and pass the radio button id to the `function RadioCheck` you can use the button value to simplify the code. For example:

```
<form>
   Yes <input type="radio" onclick="RadioCheck('yes')" name="radio" id="yes" value="inline" /> 
   No <input type="radio" onclick="RadioCheck('no')" name="radio" id="no"  value="none" />
</form>

<div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none">
   this div can be hidden and revealed
</div>

<script>
   function RadioCheck(id) {
       var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
       document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display = value;
   }
</script>
```